# Passing generic classes and objects to a Java method

Tags: java, android, generics

I want to replace the following with generics:

- `for (Post post : postResponse.getResults()) {`, where `Post` can be any POJO.
- `List<Post> posts = postResponse.getResults();` where `List<Post>` can be a list of anything I pass into it.

What would my method call and method body look like?

**Different examples of method calls:**

```
retrieveData(mCardAdapter, new Post(), Post.class);
retrieveData(mCardAdapter, new Contact(), Contact.class);
retrieveData(mCardAdapter, new Product(), Product.class);
retrieveData(mCardAdapter, new Booking(), Booking.class);
```

**Method:**

```
private void retrieveData(final CardAdapter mCardAdapter, final Object<T> postObject, Class<T> postClass) {
        RetrofitService service = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(RetrofitService.class, RetrofitService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT);
        service.getPosts()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<PostResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public final void onCompleted() {
                        setRefreshingFalse();
                        Log.e("RetrofitService", "Retrofit Request Completed!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public final void onError(Throwable e) {
                        setRefreshingFalse();
                        Log.e("RetrofitService", e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public final void onNext(PostResponse postResponse) {
                        if (postResponse != null) {

                            Log.e("RetrofitService", "Returned objects: " + postResponse.getResults());

                            for (postObject post : postResponse.getResults()) {
                                Log.e("RetrofitService", post.getObjectId() + ": " + post.getText());
                            }

                            setRefreshingFalse();

                            mCardAdapter.clear();
                            List<postClass> posts = postResponse.getResults();
                            mCardAdapter.addData(posts);

                        } else {
                            Log.e("RetrofitService", "Object returned is null.");
                        }

                    }

                });
    }
```

I'm getting `Unknown class: 'tClass'` and `Unknown class: 'postClass'`. Obviously this is not the way to do it so perhaps treat what I've shown above as pseduo-code. Does it makes sense what I'm trying to? I really want to generify this `retrieveData` method so that I can be used to query differences classes.

To help with understanding. **What I want to avoid:**

```
retrievePosts(mCardAdapter);
retrieveUsers(mCardAdapter);

private void retrievePosts(final CardAdapter mCardAdapter) {
        RetrofitService service = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(RetrofitService.class, RetrofitService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT);
        service.getPosts()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<PostResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public final void onCompleted() {
                        setRefreshingFalse();
                        Log.e("RetrofitService", "Retrofit Request Completed!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public final void onError(Throwable e) {
                        setRefreshingFalse();
                        Log.e("RetrofitService", e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public final void onNext(PostResponse postResponse) {
                        if (postResponse != null) {
                            Log.e("RetrofitService", "Returned objects: " + postResponse.getResults());

                            for (Post post : postResponse.getResults()) {
                                Log.e("RetrofitService", post.getObjectId() + ": " + post.getText());
                            }

                            /*for (Post post : postResponse.getResults()) {
                                mCardAdapter.addData(post);
                            }*/

                            setRefreshingFalse();

                            mCardAdapter.clear();
                            List<Post> posts = postResponse.getResults();
                            mCardAdapter.addData(posts);

                        } else {
                            Log.e("RetrofitService", "Object returned is null.");
                        }

                    }

                });
    }

    private void retrieveUsers(final CardAdapter mCardAdapter) {
        RetrofitService service = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(RetrofitService.class, RetrofitService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT);
        service.getUsers()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<PostResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public final void onCompleted() {
                        setRefreshingFalse();
                        Log.e("RetrofitService", "Retrofit Request Completed!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public final void onError(Throwable e) {
                        setRefreshingFalse();
                        Log.e("RetrofitService", e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public final void onNext(PostResponse postResponse) {
                        if (postResponse != null) {
                            Log.e("RetrofitService", "Returned objects: " + postResponse.getResults());

                            for (User user : userResponse.getResults()) {
                                Log.e("RetrofitService", user.getObjectId() + ": " + user.getText());
                            }

                            /*for (Post post : postResponse.getResults()) {
                                mCardAdapter.addData(post);
                            }*/

                            setRefreshingFalse();

                            mCardAdapter.clear();
                            List<User> users = userResponse.getResults();
                            mCardAdapter.addData(users);

                        } else {
                            Log.e("RetrofitService", "Object returned is null.");
                        }

                    }

                });
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Post` can be any Pojo? How do you plan on calling methods on it if you don't care what kind of object it will be.

Comment: The method just calls the retrofit request. It shouldn't matter what I pass into it.

Comment: I just want to completely reuse that method. Like, this time you're calling Posts. Then next time you're calling Contacts, People, whatever really.

Comment: Is there a super class?

Comment: Are you trying to implement something like `Arrays.asList`? If so, you can use that as a template.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you want to have a generic method for different classes. I did not see that you are adding something to the List so this might work for you.

```
private <clazz> void retrieveData(final Class<?> clazz) {
 for (clazz post : postResponse.getResults()) {
    // you can't do anything here since clazz can be anything
  }
  List<clazz> posts = postResponse.getResults();
}
```

Comment: I get a warning in the method head that ``final Class<?> clazz`` is never used even though I use it here: ``List<clazz> posts = clazzResponse.getResults();``. I call the method like this: ``retrievePosts(mCardAdapter, Post.class);``

Comment: @santafebound That should not be a problem